Resize filesystem
For the disk
Disk /dev/vda: 1636GB

this is the result from parted print free command.
 3      427GB   1100GB  673GB   primary   ext4
        1100GB  1636GB  537GB             Free Space

The primary ext4 filesystem is mounted at let say /example.
How should i resize the filesystem to take over all the remaining space (total of ~1.1TB)? The filesystem is up and running.
Thanks in advance...

Possible duplicate? https://serverfault.com/questions/509468/how-to-extend-an-ext4-partition-and-filesystem

This question is similar to: How to extend an ext4 partition and filesystem?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I’m voting to close this question because its already answered in the linked post on serverfault.

So is it generally safe to perform parted > resizepart 3 (to resize the disk partition) and then resize2fs /dev/vda3 (to resize the filesystem). Can both be performed on the live system?

If you cannot reboot and do it offline you're doing something terribly wrong. Systems must be fault tolerant and withstand crashes/reboots/maintenance. In offline you enlarge the primary partition using gparted/fdisk/sfdisk/whatever and then resize2fs this partition.
